# SQL how to WHERE CASE WHEN x THEN BETWEEN dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, between

I am working on a SQL report that is trying to break down the year into 4 quarters. And to keep from having to run a different script depending on the year I am trying to get it to all pull from one. So what I have attempted to do is have a CASE statement in the where clause that will figure out what quarter of the year it is then tell it that x date needs to be BETWEEN dates y and z. This has resulted in many syntax errors and I can't quite find where. Would you guys be able to take a look and let me know if it is even possible?

```
`AND s.actual_arrival BETWEEN 
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) < 4 THEN YEAR(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) + '-01-01' AND YEAR(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) + '03-31 23:59:59'

    WHEN MONTH(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) > 3 AND MONTH(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) < 7  THEN YEAR(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) + '-04-01' AND YEAR(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) + '06-30 23:59:59'
    WHEN MONTH(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) > 6 AND MONTH(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) < 10  THEN YEAR(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) + '-07-01' AND YEAR(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) + '09-31 23:59:59'
    WHEN MONTH(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) > 9 THEN YEAR(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) + '-10-01' AND YEAR(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())) + '12-31 23:59:59'
END`
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I tagged the question SQL Server, because it is obviously SQL Server code.

Comment: MS SQL sorry. and thanks Gordon I missed that tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, wouldn't it be simpler to just do this?

```
and datepart(quarter, s.actual_arrival) = datepart(quarter, getdate()) and
    year(s.actual_arrival) = year(getdate())
```

Comment: There is a datepart quarter 0_0 I feel dumb now. I will test code tonight and mark question correct if no more issues arise thank you,

Comment: @Ardel "I feel dumb now"  welcome to the club.  We've got jackets, membership cards and even Saturday Night Mixers.